# how can i synchronize a directory with subdirectories over ftp using spring integration with spring batch?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-batch, spring-integration-sftp

I've been trying to use `SftpInboundFileSynchronizer` with a remote directory that contains a subdir, say /myfiles/mysubdir/lefile.txt, I have set a filter to grab the files inside the dirs:

```
mysync.setRemoteDirectory("myfiles/");
mysync.setFilter(new SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter(".*\\.txt$"));
```

And then a `SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` as my InboundChannelAdapter
I have set on the `SftpInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource` a `RecursiveDirectoryScanner` as scanner and i have no set limit to the depth or the amount of files to retrieve. I also set a `FOLLOW_LINKS` fileVisitOption on the scanner for good measure.

I am only able to pull files into the local directory from the myfiles path, but anything deeper is not copied to the local dir.
I can't for the life of me figure out if there is something I'm not doing.

**EDIT:**
What would the InboundChannelAdapter contain if I'm only going to send "/" as the directory to check with mget -R?

```
@Bean
@InboundChannelAdapter(value = "sftpChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "10"))
public MessageSource<?> myMessageSource() {
}

@Bean(name = "myGateway")
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sftpChannel")
public MessageHandler handler() {
    SftpOutboundGateway gateway =
        new SftpOutboundGateway(sftpSessionFactory(), "mget", "'myfiles/*'");

    gateway.setOutputChannelName("listSplitter");
    gateway.setOptions("-R");
    gateway.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);

    myLocalPath = Paths.get(myLocalParentDir).toRealPath().toString();

    gateway.setLocalDirectory(new File(myLocalPath));

    SftpRegexPatternFileListFilter regexFilter = new regexFilter("^.*\\.txt");
    regexFilter.setAlwaysAcceptDirectories(true);
    regexFilter.setFilter(sftpRegexPatternFileListFilter);

    return gateway;
}
```

Comment: `I am only able to pull files into the local directory from the myfiles path, but anything deeper is not copied to the local dir`: So if I understand correctly you are not able to recursively copy the remote directory to your local directory, is that correct? If yes, then probably your regexp is not correct.

Comment: Recursion on the remote directory is not supported by that component; use a gateway instead; see my answer for details.

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine yep, but from Gary's comments it seems that is not supported by the component, so will try with a gateway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recursion of the remote file system is not supported by the inbound synchronizer; use an [SftpOutboundGateway](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway) (request/reply) instead, with a recursive `mget` command.

By default, files existing in the local directory are not re-fetched; you can control that with the `FileExistsMode`.

Comment: Ok, given that i need to check the directory structure periodically, if i understand correctly i would need a SftpOutboundGateway that does mget and somewhere an inbound adapter being polled that passes a message with the path "/myfiles" to the gateway?

Comment: Yes, just a simple POJO (or lambda) inbound channel adapter will fit the bill.

Comment: I updated my question with a snippet, hope i can get some help with that.

Comment: Use a lambda for the `MessageSource` - `() -> "*"`. 10ms is a rather fast poller, though. From the documentation I pointed you to "The pattern is ignored and `*` is assumed. By default, the entire remote tree is retrieved. However, you can filter files in the tree ... ". If you don't use `*` you'll get a warning log.